# Error Microphone Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, microphone, 23.10

My laptop microphone is not working.
Do I need to install any specific drivers? I have updated everything through the software update.

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this yet?
I'm having the same issue on my Razer Blade pro